# SOQL Syntax to Return Opportunity Data via Account Object

Tags: soql, opportunity, account, relationships

I'm trying to write SOQL to access fields from both the Account and Opportunity objects *from* the Account object.  Specifically I'm trying to retrieve the Id and Name fields from Account while also returning the Amount field from Opportunity.  I'm trying to do this based on the relationship between the two objects for a specific account owner.

Here's the syntax I have so far, although it is obviously not correct:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Opportunity__r.Amount 
FROM Account 
WHERE OwnerId = '0053l000X09r9TcAAI'
AND Opportunity__r.AccountId = Id
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated; thanks!

Comment: An explantation for the downvote would be helpful; at least then I could improve the question.  :(

Comment: We seem to have someone who just loves going around and downvoting nearly everything :/ I've upvoted to even things out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOQL doesn't support arbitrary joins like most other SQL dialects do, and we can't compare a field to another field (more accurately: the RHS of a filter expression cannot be an SObject field).

What SOQL does allow us to do, though, is get at child records using a subquery. The relevant documentation here is [Relationship Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm).

```sql
SELECT 
    Id, Name,
    (SELECT Id, Amount FROM Opportunities)
FROM Account 
WHERE OwnerId = '0053l000X09r9TcAAI'
```

A parent-child subquery (in the `SELECT` clause) uses the *child relationship name*. This is typically the plural of the SObject name. If it's a custom relationship (master-detail, or lookup), i.e. if you created the relationship field yourself rather than it being a standard field provided by Salesforce, then you'd need to add `__r` to it.

A parent-child subquery gets you an embedded `List<SObject>` in the overall result, accessed using the child relationship name.

```java
for(Account acct :[SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Amount FROM Opportunities) FROM Account WHERE OwnerId = '0053l000X09r9TcAAI']){
    for(Opportunity opp :acct.Opportunities){
        system.debug(acct.Id);
        system.debug(opp.Amount);
    }
}
```

The nested loop approach is the safest way to deal with subquery results. You could access `acct.Opportunities` directly, without a loop, and treat it like any other `List`, but you'll get an error if there are too many (>= ~200) child records (when Salesforce attempts to make an internal call to "queryMore").

Comment: Nice answer, though there is a question to be asked of the questioner; why must this be done from the Account? You could equally do this from the Opportunity using the account relationship, could you not?

Comment: Another point about the SOQL RHS being a value not a field; the typical solution is to employ formula fields to perform the comparison required and then to simply test that in the SOQL against TRUE or FALSE. Clearly not specifically part of the question, but you did mention the limitation in SOQL...

Comment: @Derek F - Thanks for that detailed, helpful answer...and the link to the documentation.  Reading from there I found the explanation on how the "join" happens:  **"where the initial member of the FROM clause in the subquery is related to the initial member of the outer query FROM clause."**.  And thanks for the justice vote!

Comment: @PhilW - Yes, you could start at the Opportunity and go in reverse to Account.